# Paginação de resultados no SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, paginação

Às vezes preciso fazer consultas no SQL Server 2000 e paginar os resultados porém só existe a cláusula `TOP` que limita o número de registros retornados sem um intervalo (offset) outros bancos como MySQL ou PostgreSQL possuem isso e consulta seria assim:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela LIMIT 0, 50
ou
SELECT * FROM tabela LIMIT 50, OFFSET 0
```

Como posso contornar esse problema ou emular essa funcionalidade no SQL Server 2000.

Comment: A partir do SQl Server 2012 temos o Offset que tem exatamente a mesma função do limite. Como o upgrade não é possível ...

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro de tudo eu recomendaria um belo upgrade, contudo existe uma maneira de induzir a fazer algo semelhante

```
;WITH Results_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        Col1, Col2, ...,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SortCol1, SortCol2, ...) AS RowNum
    FROM Table
    WHERE <whatever>
)
SELECT *
FROM Results_CTE
WHERE RowNum >= @Offset
AND RowNum < @Offset + @Limit
```

Nesse [artigo do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server) de maneira bem mais completa, mostra outras possibilidades, além de dar uma explicação mais detalhada

Comment: concordo plenamente com o upgrade porém não sou eu que decido isso. Vou testar, obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Eu sei como é... triste realidade quando não podemos fazer os devidos upgrades quando queremos né? Tbm sofro com isso, principalmente quando preciso dar manutenção em .NET Framework 2.0 com Access

Answer (score 0):

A consulta abaixo tem o mesmo resulta do "limit 50, 100", ou seja traz entre do registro 51 até o 100.

```
SELECT TOP 50 *
FROM tabela 
WHERE not ID in ( 
  SELECT TOP 50 ID
  FROM   tabela
  ORDER BY ID ASC
) a 
ORDER BY ID ASC;
```