# Equivalente de Limit do MySQL no SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, tsql

Alguém sabe relacionar as diferenças entre MySQL e SQL Server, inclusive usando `LIMIT n,n`? Ou se tiverem algum link que liste as diferenças seria legal.

Exemplo

```
SELECT * FROM tabela LIMIT 50, 100
```

Como seria o equivalente em SQL Server?

Answer (score 45):

Se você estiver usando o SQLServer 2012 pode usar `OFFSET` e `FETCH`

```
SELECT * FROM Tabela 
ORDER BY coluna1
OFFSET 50 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

**Nota:**
`OFFSET` e `FETCH` só podem ser usados em conjunto com `ORDER BY`

Ver [Cláusula OFFSET FETCH](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/gg699618.aspx)

Answer (score 23):

A partir da versão SQL Server 2005, você pode usar também o [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
SELECT TOP (100) *
  FROM (
       SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY coluna1 ASC) AS row_number, *
       FROM Tabela
       ) TabelaNumerada
 WHERE row_number > 50
```

melhor ainda filtrando com `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
       SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY coluna1 ASC) AS row_number, *
       FROM Tabela
       ) TabelaNumerada
 WHERE row_number BETWEEN 51 AND 150
```

Answer (score 14):

Vou colocar uma outra forma, sem group by, sem tabelas temporárias, apenas um select simples. A consulta abaixo tem o mesmo resulta do "limit 50, 100", ou seja traz entre do registro 51 até o 100.

```
SELECT TOP 50 *
FROM tabela 
WHERE not ID in ( 
  SELECT TOP 50 ID
  FROM   tabela
  ORDER BY ID ASC
) a 
ORDER BY ID ASC;
```

Comment: Não tão simples quanto o MySQL, mas simples para o MSSQL

Comment: Acredito que esse código funcione no sql server 2000, se souber mais alguma forma, deixe sua resposta nessa pergunta: [paginação de registros sql server 2000](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10049/paginacao-de-resultados-no-sql-server-2000)

Comment: Na verdade "limit 50, 100" quer dizer "pule" 50 e "liste" 100, ou seja, do registro 51 até o 150

Answer (score 2):

Eu fiz uma gambiarra funcional e rápida:

Criei uma VIEW com o SELECT abaixo sem condicionar Where:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY p.idprod ASC) as paginacao, [demaiscampos] FROM [tabela]
```

Depois chamei a view usando:

```
SELECT paginacao, [demaiscampos] FROM [tabela]  WHERE paginacao BETWEEN [reginicial] AND [regfinal]
```

Desta maneira consigo paginar a consulta sem sobrecarregar os processos do banco.

Também existe o método:

```
DECLARE @PageNumber AS INT, @RowspPage AS INT
SET @PageNumber = 2
SET @RowspPage = 5

SELECT * FROM (
             SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID_EXAMPLE) AS NUMBER,
                    ID_EXAMPLE, NM_EXAMPLE, DT_CREATE FROM TB_EXAMPLE
               ) AS TBL
WHERE NUMBER BETWEEN ((@PageNumber - 1) * @RowspPage + 1) AND (@PageNumber * @RowspPage)
ORDER BY ID_EXAMPLE
```

e também este:

```
--CREATING A PAGING WITH OFFSET and FETCH clauses IN "SQL SERVER 2012"
DECLARE @PageNumber AS INT, @RowspPage AS INT
SET @PageNumber = 2
SET @RowspPage = 10 

SELECT ID_EXAMPLE, NM_EXAMPLE, DT_CREATE
FROM TB_EXAMPLE
ORDER BY ID_EXAMPLE
OFFSET ((@PageNumber - 1) * @RowspPage) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @RowspPage ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução equivalente ao MySQL que não necessita de `ORDER BY` e que funciona em qualquer versão a partir do SQL Server 2000 é:

```
SELECT  TOP 100 *
FROM    Tabela 
WHERE   Coluna1 NOT IN (SELECT TOP 50 Coluna1 FROM Tabela)
```

> Lembrando que **50** refere-se a quantidade de linhas que serão
>   puladas/ignoradas e **100** a quantidade de linhas retornadas.

No SQL Server 2005/2008 uma outra opção é usar [CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Coluna1) AS Linha
    FROM    Tabela 
)
SELECT  *
FROM    CTE
WHERE   Linha BETWEEN 51 AND 150
```

Se a ordem e a versão não forem um problema o comando `LIMIT 50, 100` do [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html) é equivalente ao `[OFFSET] 50 ROWS FETCH ONLY 100 ROWS ONLY` do [SQL Server 2012](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx) conforme já citado.