# Como obter no SQL o último registro inserido de acordo com sua data

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Preciso obter um registro de uma tabela, onde esse registro é o que em termos de data foi inserido pela ultima vez.

Do gênero:

```
SELECT Ped.Quantidade
FROM ped
WHERE data <= @data
```

Mas como tenho vários registros ele me devolve todos, quando eu só quero o ultimo inserido pela data.

Comment: Amigo, qual seria o SGBD? MySql, Postgre, MS Sql?

Comment: Boas é SQL SERVER !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Selecione o último registro ordenando pela data decrecente e restringindo o número de linhas com `limit` ou `top`

```
SELECT Ped.Quantidade
FROM ped
WHERE data <=@data
ORDER BY data DESC limit 1
```

ou

```
SELECT TOP 1 Ped.Quantidade
FROM ped
WHERE data <=@data
ORDER BY data DESC
```

Comment: + 1 pela segunda consulta, mas acredito que elas podem sofrer variação de acordo com o SGBD. O ideal seria ter essa informação para uma informação mais precisa

Comment: @Reiksiel, pela `@data` tem uma cara de sql server.

Comment: perdeu, a primeira consulta não consegui rodar, poderia confirmar ela? rodei no MS Sql Server

Comment: @Reiksiel, no sql server o `limit` é  `top` nas versões mais recentes existem outras palavras chaves para fazer a a paginação de resultados, veja essa [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10635/equivalente-de-limit-do-mysql-no-sql-server)