# Começar Consulta em linha determinada no Sql SERVER

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

```
SELECT * FROM Customers LIMIT 3,9;
```

Tentei assim mais não funcionou

Comment: Acredito que [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10635/equivalente-de-limit-do-mysql-no-sql-server) irá lhe ajudar.

Comment: SELECT TOP 50 *
FROM tabela 
WHERE not ID in ( 
  SELECT TOP 50 ID
  FROM   tabela
  ORDER BY ID ASC
) a 
ORDER BY ID ASC;

Comment: Esse aqui eu fiz manis não pega da forma que eu quero

Comment: quero começar do final na linha 14000 até oque veio depois dela