# Cláusula similar ao LIMIT do MySQL em MSSQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sintaxe, select-limit

Preciso executar a *query* abaixo no PHP com SQL Server, no entanto não consigo utilizar a cláusula `LIMIT` ausente nas *queries* da Microsoft.

```
$SqlTabelaAtual="SELECT * 
         FROM BusinessCadTabPreco
         RIGHT JOIN BusinessCadTabPrecoItem ON BusinessCadTabPreco.CdTabela = BusinessCadTabPrecoItem.CdTabela
         WHERE  BusinessCadTabPreco.CdEmpresa =01
         AND CdProduto =".$row['CdProduto']."
         ORDER BY  BusinessCadTabPreco.DtSincronizar DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Qual versão do mssql?

Comment: acredito ser 2015, rodei um php_info, não vi nada nas info do mssql. Como posso testar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O SQL Server usa a sintaxe [`TOP`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms189463(v=sql.110)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397):

```
$SqlTabelaAtual = "SELECT TOP 1 * 
         FROM BusinessCadTabPreco
         RIGHT JOIN BusinessCadTabPrecoItem ON BusinessCadTabPreco.CdTabela = BusinessCadTabPrecoItem.CdTabela
         WHERE  BusinessCadTabPreco.CdEmpresa =01
         AND CdProduto =".$row['CdProduto']."
         ORDER BY  BusinessCadTabPreco.DtSincronizar DESC"
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/LimitSqlServer.sql).

A versão 2012 e posteriores permite a [sintaxe ANSI com `OFFSET`  `FETCH`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms188385(v=sql.110)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Comment: A partir de qual versão funciona com`TOP` no final da consulta?

Comment: Se não me engano 2005. Ninguém deveria estar usando uma versão anterior.

Comment: Ainda bem que o SQL Server 2000 não é mais problema meu :D, pq é sofrido ... acho que ainda não aposentaram ele.

Comment: Concordo, é que pensei que fosse algo recente, testei aqui não funcionou, acho que `TOP` no `sql-server` Vem sempre depois do `select`e não no final da consulta. @bigown

Comment: @rubStackOverflow oops, você tem razão, corrigido :)

Answer (score 5):

Dependendo do caso `TOP` é adequado para limitar linhas de uma consulta, em versões mais recentes existe outras clásulas mais flexiveis.

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM tabela.
```

**Relacionada:**

[Paginação de resultados no SQL Server 2000](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10049/91)

Comment: obrigado @rray isso ajudou !